# How does one parse an XMI (or XML) file

Tags: dart

How can I parse an XML file in dart?

I've found https://github.com/prujohn/dart-xml but was unsuccessful using it on a complete file (after removing the header and just including the uml:Model element there were issues with PIs).

I need to parse an XMI file exported from Altova UModel containing UML. If this particular battery is not included at present - what is the time-frame for its inclusion?

Comment: Any error you receive ? what actually could not be parsed ?

Comment: I suggest opening a bug at https://github.com/prujohn/dart-xml/issues and pasting in the error that you receive when you try to open the file.

Comment: Is this a browser-based app?

Comment: No it is not browser based. My workaround was to use ruby script to convert to json and then Dart does fine.

Comment: I created: http://pastebin.com/1W0F1d4k that demonstrates the problem, likely related to 'Namespace ... not declared in scope'. Interesting, when I put try/catch and print the exception I only get partial text.i.e.(main() {try {XML.parse(xmi);} catch(e) { print("Error is $e"); }}) does not print "Error is" just "<uml:Model xmi:id="U00000001-7510-11d9-86f2-0". No try/catch gives 0 stack frame of:
#0      XmlParser._parseTag (package:xml/src/xml_parser.dart:190:9)

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is a package that you can use here:

http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/xml

Comment: I believe that is the package referred (the pub package points to the prujohn dart-xml) to in the question - which does not work for this xml file.